# PDO using PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE and __construct() call?

Tags: php, constructor, pdo

I'm trying to create a new instance of `Setting` object calling **`__construct()`** method with PHP PDO and constrain **PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE**. Unfortunatly i'm getting this warning (and binding doesn't work).

***How can pass column values to the constructor method?***

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Setting::__construct() in pdo.php.
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: key in pdo.php.

```
class Setting
{

    protected $key, $value, $displayable;

    public function __construct($key, $value = null, $displayable = 1)
    {
        $this->key         = $key;
        $this->value       = $value;
        $this->displayable = $displayable > 0;
    }

}

while($mashup = current($mashups))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `key`, value, displayable
        FROM setting WHERE mashup_id = :id');

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $mashup->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $settings = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
       'Setting');
}

$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constructor specifies `$key` parameter as mandatory, because it has no default value provided:

```
public function __construct(
    $key // <---no default value
    $value = null,
    $displayable = 1
)
```

So, when you are doing this:

```
$settings = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Setting');
```

you get `warning: Missing argument 1 for Setting::__construct() in pdo.php`.
The error is thrown only for parameter `$key` because this has no default value and you aren't providing any.

The correct use of `fetchAll` is by providing the optional parameter `$constructorArgs` (see [available signatures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-description)):

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
    'classname', 
    <array of arguments, with same order used in constructor>
);
```

So, in your case:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
    'Setting', 
    array('your-value-for-key-parameter') // nullable params can be omitted or partially specified, same as for any php function/method
);
```

Comment: But after calling __construct(), will it assign property again (overriding what was set in constrcutor), right?

Comment: I know this is a bit necro but.. Is it only overriding the constructor-set value because of `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`, or will that always happen?