# PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE and __construct() call using fetched data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

This question is very similar to the one already asked here: [PDO using PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE and __construct() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127693/pdo-using-pdofetch-props-late-and-construct-call)

However, the accepted answer in that question doesn't really answer how to pass *fetched* values into the constructor of the class, if that's even possible. Here's some reduced code:

```
<?php

class Course {
    private $name;
    private $code;
    private $prerequisites;

    public function __construct($name, $code) {

        if(!is_string($code) || mb_strlen($code) !== 7) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid code.');
        }

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->prerequisites = array();
    }

    public static function getAllCourses() {
        $sql = 'SELECT `name`, `code` FROM `courses` ORDER BY `code`;';
        $db = new \PDO(' ... ', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Course', array('name', 'code'));

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
```

The problem with this code is that the literal strings "name" and "code" get passed to the constructor. However I want to pass the actual values of the name and code to the constructor (obviously).

Can this be done? If yes, how? Do I use [bindColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php)?

Answer (score 1):

basically, any PDO::fetch_something() method WILL ASSIGN THE PROPERTIES.

so you just ned properties, that have the same name as the columns, as you have it correctly.
you don't even need getters or setters or a constructor!

you can pass values to the constructor of the class like this:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'Course',
    array(<value of col1>, <value of col2>));
```

note, that you do not pass the name of the columns, but the values, in the array!

but that is tricky! be sure to have set the fetchMode properly!

if \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE is set it will FIRSTLY call the __construct and SECONDLY set the properties. so the values you have passed to the __construct via the array will be overwritten.

if you haven't set \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE it will do it reverse.

just try it.

Comment: but the problem is, if you do not pass an array for your constructor, you must set default values for all the parameters in the constructor, cause PDO will call that constructor and php will throw an error, if the parameters do not match. [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134544/1961222)