# PHP FETCH_CLASS constructor issue

Tags: php, pdo, constructor

So I've started working with PDO instead of mysqli and I was looking into object mapping.
Finally got it to work, but there is a little issue I need to resolve.

First of all, I've got a little database thingy right here.

```
try {
    $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $statement = $query->execute(array('email'=>$email));
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");

    return $result;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    return 'Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
}
```

And now there's the class User, which is like this:

```
class User {
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $date_registered;
    private $ip_address;
    private $is_activated;
    private $activation_token;

    public function __construct($username, $email, $password, $ipAddress, $isActivated, $activationToken) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->ip_address = $ipAddress;
        $this->is_activated = $isActivated;
        $this->activation_token = $activationToken;
    }
```

The big issue right now is, FETCH_CLASS first fills the variables and then checks the constructor... As you can see, my constructor needs parameters, so now I'm having a bucketload of errors.
I've also tested it without the constructor, and then the FETCH_CLASS works perfectly. But, I need the constructor. I guess I could always create a different function which does the same as the constructor, but if possible I would like to keep it this way.

So, is there any way I could solve this little constructor problem without removing the constructor?

Comment: Will the database always supply a value for each of these fields, or will some be null?

Comment: [This answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127693/pdo-using-pdofetch-props-late-and-construct-call) making use of `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` and adding a `null` default for each of your params to the constructor like `function __construct($username=null,$email=null....)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski for now every field is filled but it could be null in the future. I know I'm not catching everything at the moment, that's my next step. But I could use some advice :) Anyway, your suggestion solved my problem, thank you! And merry christmas buddy :)