# PHP - Constructing a class with PDO - Warning: Missing argument

Tags: php, mysql, object, pdo

I have the following select statement which I am constructing a user object:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user.User_ID, user.User_Name
        FROM user");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS| PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'User');
```

I have the following class in a separate file, included with -  require "User.php":

```
class User
{
private $User_ID;
private $User_Name;

public function __construct($User_ID, $User_Name)
{
   $this->User_ID = $User_ID;
   $this->User_Name =$User_Name;
}
```

I get the following warnings and notices -

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for User::__construct()
Notice: Undefined variable: User_ID
```

It works fine but I turned on warnings etc as I am tidying up my code.

I have looked at other questions on here but the solutions don't seem to help and thought a fresh pair of eyes could help. A thought I had was I should have been passing an array in the setFetchMode() as the documentation states but that still seems to cause issues.

What is the correct way to create a class in PDO?

Comment: You're missing a `");` on your prepare() call, which I'm hoping is just a typo while entering the question here...

Comment: @MarcB Thanks - yes just a typo

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO using PDO::FETCH\_PROPS\_LATE and \_\_construct() call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127693/pdo-using-pdofetch-props-late-and-construct-call)

Comment: I hope you're not writing your own ORM when there's several out there like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or the sort that ships with a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use arguments to User constructor, you need to use the third parameter in setFetchMode

> public bool PDOStatement::setFetchMode ( int $PDO::FETCH_CLASS ,
>   string $classname , array $ctorargs )

In your case

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS| PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'User',
array('User_ID','User_name'));
```

or just provide default values for the constructor.

See [the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php).